# Is there a Python alternative for sqlite3 which doesn't use a database?

Tags: python

I was working with sqlite3, but it takes way too long to connect to a database.

I don't have that much data, so I was wondering if there was an alternative which doesn't connect to anything, just uses variables.

If there is a module for that please could you let me know? Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried to work with [in-memory databases with sqlite3?](https://www.sqlite.org/inmemorydb.html)

Comment: Out of curiosity, what is your definition of "way too long"? My experiance with SQLite is the direct opposite. If you don't have that much data (lets say, some Megabytes), the database is lightning fast. We're talking about miliseconds to query something & getting the answer.

Comment: No, I mean connecting to it - the queries are fine, but at the start of the program it takes 5-6 seconds which can be reduced

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check out the python library `badsql`

You can read the documentation [here](https://github.com/nayakrujul/badsql/blob/main/README.md)